# Website is faster on second load (with cache disabled on both first and second load)

Tags: browser, cache

First load without cache: 1.9 seconds

Second load without cache: 1.3 seconds

If I wait 1 minute then it takes 1.9 seconds again to load

Is there some hidden 1 minute cache in browsers or Windows that can't be turned off? Or apache?

It's hard to figure out if it's the browser causing this, or if it's the server, since external resources like AJAX json fetches to other servers also take longer on first/slow load.

It seems to be every website that does this

Thanks

Comment: Could be DNS caching. You should clear that as well before testing.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does cache DNS requests for future use, so you may have a culprit there, if you're on Windows. I think all OSes do that, saves on the bandwidth and provides a better user experience.

Comment: The DNS lookups take a maximum of 20 ms to the websites I'm connecting to. I can't figure out why loading a page, without cache, takes 2 seconds the first time and 1 second right after. It seems to be every website and every browser